# Determining odds in Blackjack

Tags: recreational-mathematics, card-games

How do you determine the different odds in Blackjack? For example, what would be the difference in odds from using 1, 2, or 3 decks? Also, what would be the difference in odds if you shuffle the deck before each hand instead of after the cards are used up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, as you use more decks you are approaching drawing with replacement instead of without.  The chance of getting a blackjack with one deck is 2(4/52)(16/51), with the 2 being whether you draw the ace first, 4/52 drawing an ace, and 16/51 drawing a 10 count.  If you have a huge number of decks this becomes 2(4/52)(16/52).  If you don't shuffle before the hand, it is impacted by the cards you have seen go by.  If all the aces have already been drawn, the probability is zero.

Answer (score 3):

[Edward Oakley Thorp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_O._Thorp) went into depth on this subject with his book ${\bf Beat \,\, the \,\, Dealer,}$ which demonstrated mathematically how the house advantage can be overcome in blackjack by [card counting.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_counting)